# Data Explorer Recent Queries not Updating

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

The [recent queries view](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=recent) in the data explorer seems to be broken. It shows, since quite a while, that Mark Hurd asked for Quick Answers, zero seconds ago. The view doesn't seem to be updated by new queries.

**Edit:**
Actually, if you save a query, it seems to be inserted in the list, but only *after* the top two lines. The "Quick Answers" always stay at top, with "0s ago". If you click the link to the query you also get a server error.

**Edit 2:**
The problem with recent queries seems to be fixed now. One of the problematic queries was [this](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/117/quick-answers), which still gives a server runtime error if called directly.

Comment: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=recent

Comment: @sth I deleted it, for some reason it was a saved query with no underlying query, I have no idea how it happened but will code some protection. (simple make the queryid not nullable)

Comment: re 117 giving an error, I really should be showing a 404 there, I should sort that out

Comment: That Quick Answers query was mostly timing out (which needs a better UI outcome). I tried changing to Meta and the query disappeared. At one stage I saved the query but it didn't appear in my Save Queries tab.

Comment: @waffles BTW Thanks for the OpenId merge.

Comment: @mark no worries, it can not happen again due to schema changes, also I should just hide the save toolbar when you start typing stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all fixed now, I added an additional "everything" tab for those curious to snoop on the queries others are writing and improved the tool tips.