# Slow queries don't stop, you just don't see the result, unless you find it in "everything"

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

If you locate my most recent "Quick Answers" [result](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/2794/quick-answers), note it *does have* a result, but note that it took **104 seconds**!

This is much more than the Ajax timeout, but clearly the query didn't stop. This suggests a denial of service attack is possible by requesting a number of very long lasting queries.

The [feature-request] is a better UI when Ajax times out.

The [bug] is the SQL query is not aborted.

<sub>*(This was promoted from a comment I was going to add [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53123/data-explorer-recent-queries-not-updating).)*</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const int QUERY_TIMEOUT = 120;
command.CommandTimeout = QUERY_TIMEOUT;
```

It would seem my http request timeout is not inline with my query timeout, besides some browsers hard code timeouts and ignore the web servers. Perhaps I should change it from a sync call to:  submit job -> get job id -> poll it. Its a big change though.

**EDIT** I upped the request timeout to 120 so it should not happen anymore, I hope.